# jQuery: Automatically prefill an input with the current time hours, mins, secs

Tags: jquery

I'm looking at identifying an input e.g.

```
<input class="date" type="text" value=""></input>
```

and with the vale="" part automatically inset the time, which changes on every refresh in a format like this; 12:34:55 - so it grabs the hour:minutes:seconds.

so the result would be:

```
<input class="date" type="text" value="12:34:55"></input>
```

Comment: What problem are you having when you do this? Just run some code in the `$(document).ready()` handler that calculates the time string and does `$(".date").val(timestring)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
  function startTime()
{
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
 // add a zero in front of numbers<10
 m=checkTime(m);
 s=checkTime(s);
$('.date').val(h+":"+m+":"+s);
 t=setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
 }

function checkTime(i)
{
  if (i<10)
  {
  i="0" + i;
  }
  return i;
 }
 setInterval(function(){startTime()},1000);
```

**[Wokring Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3UTC/)**

Comment: Hey Milind, Thanks for such a quick response here. This looks pretty sweet, may I ask, does the 'value' change with each second?, so if they press submit and pass the value="" (time) - then a couple of seconds later press submit again on the same page (without refresh) - that it carries across the new time?

Comment: It will get the current time that input box will have. You should be disabling submit after one click.

Comment: It surer does, amazing thank you. 

May I have one more comment please, how's best to add the date at the start of this? e.g. 2014 12:34:55 - Should I post a new question?

Comment: sorry i did not get you.can you picyure it more

Comment: Sure, so <input type="" value="2014 12:43:55"></input> - So we're literally just adding a date with a 'live' counter

Comment: Hope that makes sense.

Comment: yes we do.on every second.

Comment: Sorry, i'm probably not being clear: You've managed to insert the hours:mins:secs > I trieed including the year e.g. y:h:m:s - but it didn't work. So i'm looking to add the Year e.g. 2014 in that as well.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y3UTC/1/

Comment: That's absolutely perfect, a sincere thank you for helping me today, you're a star!